# Anyone can explain this Javascript data structure?

Tags: javascript

I found this code below:

```
var this.something = {};

var box = {};

box.id = X[0];
box.name = X[1]
box.address = X[2];

if(!this.something.ids[box.id]){                    
  this.something.ids[box.id] = 1;
  this.something.datas.push(box);
}
```

How can I change "box.name" that has "box.id" = 'z' in the "this.something" data structure?

Anyone can help me here?

I need to reference the "this.something" and edit the associated "box" array. But, I don't know how.

Thanks.

Comment: add an if conditional statement.

Comment: The code has syntax errors to begin with.

Comment: `something` appears to be an empty object so the condition `!this.something.ids[box.id]` should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.something.datas.length; i++){
    var box = this.something.datas[i];
    if(box.id === 'z'){
        box.name = "New Name";
    }
}
```

You can make this into a function of course

```
var Something = function(){
    this.ids = [];
    this.datas = [];

    this.addBox = function(X){
        var box = {};

        box.id = X[0];
        box.name = X[1]
        box.address = X[2];

        if(!this.ids[box.id]){                    
            this.ids[box.id] = 1;
            this.datas.push(box);
        }
    }

    this.getBoxById = function(id){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.datas.length; i++){
            var box = this.datas[i];
            if(box.id === id){
                return box;
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    }
}

var something = new Something();
...
var box = something.getBoxById('z');
if(box){
    box.name = "new name";
}
```

Comment: I think this might work. I was thinking there is simpler solution or any other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, you cannot declare properties as variables: `var this.something = {}` is wrong. Use `this.something = {}` instead.

what is `X` object? instead of having `this.something` as object `{}` with properties as arrays `.ids` and `.datas` you should use `this.something` as array `[]` and simply push there your `box` object. then you can simply loop your array and made changes only to that elements, which id is you searching.

```
//Better use array, not object with 2 properties of arrays for ids and objects.
this.something = [];

//Create box object and push to array.
var box = {
   id: X[0],
   name: X[1],
   address: X[2]
}; //You also can create object as you did, but this way is short-hand definition of object with custom properties.

//Push box to array
this.something.push(box)

var boxIdToChange = 'abc';

// Instant edit when you still have access to your 'box' object.
if (box.id === boxIdToChange){
      //Make your changes to 'elem' object here.
      elem.name = 'New name';
      elem.address = 'Different address than original';
}

// If you want to make changes later, for example after creating multiple box elements.
for (var i = 0; i<this.something.length;i++){
   var elem = this.something[i];
   if (elem.id === boxIdToChange){
      //Make your changes to 'elem' object here.
      elem.name = 'New name';
      elem.address = 'Different address than original';
   }
}
```

Comment: if your current code is in working state, then be aware of simply changing `this.something` from object to array, as it may cause errors at other functions which uses `this.something` as object. In that case you can still use your object, but then in `for` function make loop throw `this.something.datas` array.

Answer (score 0):

if I get what you're saying, shouldn't just:

```
if (box.id == "z") box.name = "whatever";
```

be what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I meant, the "box" that has been pushed to the "this.something" variable.

Comment: why not check it before pushing it into the array? Plus maybe u should clean up your code a bit as well like others have pointed out.